# Referencing Non-embedded Fonts

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

#### Description:

Currently i'm working on a project that requires to have certain assets to be exchangeable, i.e. can be replaced by the user. For convenience everything is collected in different **ResourceDictionaries** and merged within **ApplicationResources**.

This works fine, except for **FontFamilies** that aren't referenced via an URI, i.e.

```
<Element UriSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Path/To/Asset.ext" />
```

#### Already Tested:

Working (but not desired):

```
<FontFamily x:Key="fontMain">X:\Path\To\Asset\FontFile.ttf#FontName</FontFamily>
```

Not working:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="fontMain">./Assets/Fonts/FontFile.ttf#FontName</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="fontMain">./Assets/Fonts/#FontName</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="fontMain">/Assets/Fonts/FontFile.ttf#FontName</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="fontMain">/Assets/Fonts/#FontName</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="fontMain">/AssemblyName;component/Assets/Fonts/FontFile.ttf#FontName</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="fontMain">/AssemblyName;component/Assets/Fonts/#FontName</FontFamily>
```

#### Question:

*This part should be obvious, but i write it anyway.* What do i have to do, to make it work? A solution via C# isn't desired, because the fonts are needed for the design (WIP).

At the moment I've embedded the fonts, to keep working. But it's obviously not a permanent solution.

#### Research Sources:

- Pretty much every article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) on the matter
- Countless articles on [CodeProject](http://codeproject.com)
- And everything [Google](http://google.com) could find

*Won't list all articles separately, because there are to many to list them here.*

Comment: Both `FontFamily="FolderName/#FontName"` and `FontFamily="/FolderName/#FontName"` work for me... not sure why it doesn't for you.

Comment: Probably because i'm referencing them from a sub folder, within the assembly. Have to check on that.

Comment: Just checked all variations listed above from inside the App.xaml (store in the project root), still no luck.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your question... that syntax works for loading from actual font files in a folder... have you tried that?

Comment: Everything under "Already Tested", was tried before, including your approach. Even from several different locations.